# Bussproof with axiom labels

Tags: labels, bussproofs

How do I use `\LeftLabel{}` and `\RightLabel{}` along with just `\AxiomC{}`?

The following only displays the axiom

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{prooftree}
        \LeftLabel{bar}
        \RightLabel{baz}
        \AxiomC{foo}
    \end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a MWE please, instead of fragments only?

Comment: What does MWE mean? I added the rest of the code

Comment: After being here for almost two years: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: I guess I've had enough information in the past ;)

Comment: You must have an `interference` line, say with `\UnaryInfC{...}`, otherwise the labels aren't displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `bussproofs` needs an `interference` line (terminology by the package) which is generated with `\UnaryInfC{some content}` -- only after using that the labels from `\RightLabel` and `\LeftLabel` are shown.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{prooftree}
        \AxiomC{foo}
        \LeftLabel{bar}
        \RightLabel{baz}
        \UnaryInfC{Yo!}
        \singleLine
    \end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my incompetent proof ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a bare axiom counts as a valid proof tree. I think you'd want something like

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{prooftree}
        \AxiomC{}
        \LeftLabel{bar}
        \RightLabel{baz}
        \UnaryInfC{foo}
    \end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[PDF docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20130503023215/http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/bussproofs/BussGuide2_Smith2012.pdf) suggest the labels are for inference lines, not bare axioms, so without an inference, there won't be any labels.